# Loading only a list of rows using Panda read_csv function - Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like to know if there is an option for the `pandas.read_csv` function  which allow me load only a certain list of rows from the original csv file.

The csv file is really big, and I cant load the whole file due to a lack of memory.
Is there an option like:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file, <b>'read_only'</b> = list_to_read) ?
```

with `list_to_read = [0,2,10]` for example (this will only read the row 0, the row 2 and the row 10)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: skiprows parameter accepts a list so if you know the number of lines you can do something like `set(range(n)).difference(list_to_read)` but I don't think that would be efficient. Other than that, parsing line by line to a list and converting to a DataFrame seems like a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you go over the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for `read_csv` you will find the `nrows` kwarg:

> nrows : int, default None
>   Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files

Note however that this will read the `n` first rows from the file, not arbitrary lines (ie you **can't** provide it `[0, 2, 10]` and expect it to read the first, third and eleventh rows)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to iteratively update the dataframe as you read through the file.  This is not a fast process, but it will get only the rows of interest into a dataframe without pulling the entire file into memory.

```
import pandas as pd

col_list = ['columnA', 'columnB', ... ]  #fill in your data columns
row_list = [0, 3, 10, ... ]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_list)
row_number = 0

with open('path/to/file', 'rb') as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp.xreadlines()):
        if i in row_list:
            data_line = map(float, line.strip().split(','))  #assumes all columns are floats
            df.loc[row_number] = data_line
            row_number += 1
```